# Laravel Testing User::store() with phpunit

Tags: laravel-4, phpunit

I'm learning both Laravel and UnitTesting at the moment, so this may be a stupid question.

I'm getting stuck on how to best test the controller function below:

**UserController:**

```
public function store()
{
    $input = Input::all();
    $user = new User($input);

    if( ! $user->save()){
        return Redirect::back()->withInput()->withErrors($user->getErrors());
    }

    return Redirect::to('/user');
}
```

**here's the test as I have it so far:**

```
    /**
 * @dataProvider providerTestUserStoreAddsUsersCorrectly
 */
public function testUserStoreAddsUsersCorrectly($first_name, $last_name, $email, $password)
{
    $response = $this->call('POST', 'user', array('first_name'=>$first_name, 'last_name'=>$last_name, 'email'=>$email, 'password'=>$password));
}

public function providerTestUserStoreAddsUsersCorrectly(){
    return array(
        array("FirstName", "LastName", "Email@add.com", "pass1234")
    );

}
```

This is actually working and adding the user to the db correctly, but I'm not sure how to test the output / what assertions to use as the response should be to add the user to the db and to redirect to the `/user` page.

How do I finish this test?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to check success status then you can simply send status code from your controller
and check status in test

```
public function store()
{
    $input = Input::all();
    $user = new User($input);

    if( !$user->save() ){
        return array("status"=>'failed');
    }

    return array("status"=>'success');
}

public function testUserStoreAddsUsersCorrectly($first_name, $last_name, $email, $password)
{
    $requested_arr = [
        'first_name' => $first_name,
        'last_name' => $last_name,
        'email' => $email,
        'password' => $password
    ];
    $response = $this->call('POST', 'user', $requested_arr);
    $data = json_decode($response ->getContent(), true);

    if ($data['status']) {
        $this->assertTrue(true);
    } else {
        $this->assertTrue(false);
    }
}
```